# Move existing point to a new location

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, arcgis-pro, point, move

I have a point shapefile that I have updated the Location for.

Attribute for {Existing_Lat}, {Existing_Long} and {Lidar_Lat}, {Lidar_Long}, 4 Fields.

I need to move the point from the existing Lat/Long to the LiDAR Lat/Long with all its associated attributes.

I am using ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro.

Comment: Which of the ArcMap and ArcGIS Pro applications do you wish to ask about in this particular question?  What have you tried?

Comment: I have ArcMap and ArcPro. I have done the manual work of just joining the 2 Point Layers (so that it keeps the attributes) and creating new Records, then deleting the old records. Just wondering if a pyton script would move them and not necessarily create new records. Im not a pro in pyton, but can copy, replace, paste, and run if possible.

Comment: I think you’ll find an earlier Q&A on this site that describes using the field calculator to do this in ArcMap.

Comment: If you wish to ask about using ArcPy then you’ll need to make a code attempt. Code on request is not a service we offer but we do help when users are stuck with a code snippet which they present.

Answer (score 1):

Use the field calculator on the SHAPE field, specify the parser as python, provide this expression:

```
arcpy.Point( !Lidar_Long!, !Lidar_Lat!)
```